Laser resonance phase shift
I understand in classical mechanics, for an driving force to be resonant with the oscillator and give force to it, there must be a $\pi/2$ phase shift (lag).
My first question: is this the same for the oscillation between a two level system that is driven with a laser?
When the laser is resonant, does it always carry a $\pi/2$ phase shift?
My second question: for a two-level system, when a laser is red-detuned(lower energy level) and blue-detuned(higher energy level) from a certain resonance frequency, does the phase difference between them necessarily be $\pi$?
Thanks
